# order and split data for boxplot visualization

Tags: r, loops, vector, seq, rep

I'm newest in R and i have some trouble.

I want to create a vector of length 45918.

For the first 1000 values I want to put 1000
    the second 1000 values : 2000

So it would be something like that c(1000,1000,1000,...,2000,2000,..,3000,..., : 45000,45000,45000)

It's like a `rep(1000,len=45918, by=1000)`.

I want this because I have another vector of 45918 values. So i want to assign at each value a "rank".

After that I want to make 45 boxplot of my data. So that's why I'm trying to make this.

If you have another idea to create my boxplot and don't create this vector it's ok for me.

Comment: `rep(seq(1000, 46000, by=1000), each=1000, length.out=45918)` ? BTW: after the 45000-th element your value is 46000, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks you !
From 45000 to 45918 I want to be 45000. It's for my plot

Comment: No sorry, 46000 but i will have just 918 value but it's ok.
thanks you